# How do I pass a ulong type argument to a C# function from Python?

Tags: python, c#, python.net

From Python, I am calling a C# function which is in a dll. This is done by "python.net". Most of the functions can be called correctly in Python. However, there is one function I have a problem because of data type on the argument.

In C#, there is a function, that takes an unsigned long type:

```
bool SetValueAsInt64U(ulong rValue);
```

In Python, I am calling it with

```
SetValueAsInt64U(22);
```

This gives the error message:
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for SetValueAsInt64U:(<class 'int'>)

I also tried to use the ctypes, and call the function like:

```
SetValueAsInt64U(c_ulong(22));
```

This gives a similar error:
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for SetValueAsInt64U: (<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>)

For more information, I am showing a correct call.
In C#, there is another function with signed argument:

```
bool SetValueAsInt64(long rValue)
```

In Python, I can call the function without any error message, for example:

```
SetValueAsInt64(-5);
```

So the question is how can I call the C# function with the unsigned type of argument from Python?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do in this situation is to just make a overload of that method to take a int argument, python will parse it as a ulong if it's reaching the maximum int range 2,147,483,647.

Comment: Thanks! Shall this method be added in C# or in Python?

Comment: Add this method in C# yes

Comment: Yes, I tried to add overload method in C#. It is a way to solve the problem. However I prefer a way that does not need to change C# code, because my C# dll is provided to other C# users also. So if there is another possibility, I do not want to mix C# layer with something just for Python. See the solution I finally found with numpy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

dp.SetValueAsInt64U(np.uint64(22));
```

This approach does not need to change C# code. It is a solution in Python code.

The numpy data types are:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a NumPy dependency, you can just cast your integer to `System.UInt64`:

```py
import clr
import System

SetValueAsInt64U(System.UInt64(22))
```